# INSERT when used in SQL Server Management Studio = Question marks

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ssms, collation, hebrew

When I insert a Hebrew string into a SQL Server database through SSMS, it appears as question marks.

The weird thing is - it only happens when the data is from SSMS. When I insert data through my app using EF, it shows up just fine.

Anyone know how to solve this? Because it doesn't appear to be a collation issue.

Comment: Please show your exact insert and your table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the string with `N'your string value'` when inserting into the table.

Answer (score 0):

i may suggest always keep note of database collation settings , you can identify the same and then read further about the same online
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;

Second thing to note is data type usually multi language system use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR  as datatype 
in your insert statement specify the string as N'STRINGVALUE'

This denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode (the N actually stands for National language character set).